# getting retrofit exception Method return type must not include a type variable or wildcard in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

```
 networkCall = NetworkCall(context)
            val responceCall = networkCall!!.getRetrofit(true).callReadMeService()
            responceCall.clone().enqueue(object : Callback<BaseResponse<*>?> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<BaseResponse<*>?>, response: Response<BaseResponse<*>?>) {
                    networkCall!!.dismissLoading()


                    web_view!!.loadData((response.body()?.data as LinkedTreeMap<*, *>)["description"] as String, "text/html", "UTF-8")
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<BaseResponse<*>?>, t: Throwable) {
                    networkCall!!.dismissLoading()

                }
            })
```

here is api method

```
@POST("stories/readme")
fun callReadMeService():   Call<BaseResponse<*>?>
```

now i am getting this exception

here is  my BaseResponse class

```
class BaseResponse<T> {

    var message: String? = null
    var status: Boolean = false
    var errors: Array<String>? = null
    var code: String? = null
    var data: T? = null
}
```

Method return type must not include a type variable or wildcard: retrofit2.Call>
    for method IApi.callReadMeService

now i can't  remove generic  data variable from BaseResponse class, cause i am using this class as a common Api parser

any solution for this

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? I have same question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, because the type info needs to be fully specified, otherwise retrofit cannot correctly generate the Service. [See this discussion](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2012).

You need to create a different API method for each type.

Comment: any annotation that can fix this?

Comment: what if I want to return Map? Kotlin force me to declare type parameters!

Comment: @HosseinNasr Your best bet might be to return a `JsonElement` and parse it into a `Map` yourself. This limitation has nothing to do with Kotlin, but with Retrofit itself.